# Serf 1.3.9 compiles as 1.3.0?

Tags: linux, svn

I'm trying to compile Subversion-1.9.7 with the serf dependency on a redhad linux.

It complains about serf not being found:

```
configure: serf library configuration via pkg-config
checking for serf-2 library... no
checking for serf-1 library... no
configure: serf library configuration via prefix
checking was serf enabled... no

An appropriate version of serf could not be found, so libsvn_ra_serf
will not be built.  If you want to build libsvn_ra_serf, please
install serf 1.3.4 or newer.

configure: error: Serf was explicitly enabled but an appropriate version was not found.
```

I installed serf using instructions from http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/basicnet/serf.html.

Oddly, although I'm compiling serf-1.3.9 it produces libserf-1.so.1.3.0. Why is it 1.3.0? and is it the cause of the issue?

This is the compiled and installed serf lib:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 427438 Sep 15 16:31 /usr/lib/libserf-1.so.1.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is more then 2 years old I will write an answer here, since I searched for hours and did only find bits and pieces:

My problem was that I was building serf with a new libressl (3.0.2). Building serf according to previously posted link works but scons check complains about an OPENSSL issue in test_sslserver.c
Starting from [this patch](https://github.com/gentoo/libressl/blob/master/net-libs/serf/files/serf-1.3.9-libressl.patch) I did the same for test/server/test_sslserver.c. (currently line 30)
Since that test is executed when configure svn it is crucial that it can be executed.
with these two patches I was finally able to build a working version of svn 1.13.0

A powershell script to build SVN can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/miicha/9940a5df75d1ea0381516752f20f8986)

Btw it is ok that it is named 1.3.0